# Python tkinter unit converter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a unit converter between cm, mm and km.

I want the values to keep changing as the user types in one of the inputs. for example if the user start typing in the `centimeter field`, I want to display the `millimeters` and `kilometers` as he types.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
    from tkinter import *

    def get_option_value(unit):
        if unit == 'Length':
            length_frame.pack()

        if unit == 'Tempratur':
            print('Tempratur')

        if unit == 'Area':
            print('Area')

        if unit == 'Volume':
            print('Volume')

    def convert_length(event, type):
        if type == 'm':
            print('do some stuff')

    if type == 'cm':
        print('do some stuff')

    if type == 'km':
        print('do some stuff')

    window = Tk()

    window.geometry('500x500')
    window.resizable(0, 0)

    t_frame = Frame(window, width=200, height=40)
    b_frame = Frame(window, width=400, height=200)

    t_frame.pack_propagate(0)
    b_frame.pack_propagate(0)

    t_frame.pack(padx=30, pady=10)
    b_frame.pack(ipadx=20, ipady=20)

    option_menu_label = Label(t_frame, text="Select Unit To Convert")
    option_menu_label.pack()
    options = ["Length", "Temprature", "Area", "Volume",]
    default_value = StringVar()
    default_value.set('Select Unit')
    option_menu = OptionMenu(t_frame, default_value, *options, command=get_option_value)

    option_menu.pack()

    # Length Converter

    length_frame = Frame(b_frame, width=50, height=50)

    mm_label = Label(length_frame, text="Millimeters").grid(row=0)
    mm = IntVar()
    mm_entry = Entry(length_frame, textvariable=mm)
    mm_entry.bind("<Key>", lambda event: convert_length(event, 'm'))

    cm_label = Label(length_frame, text="Centimeters").grid(row=1, column=0)
    cm = IntVar()
    cm_entry = Entry(length_frame, textvariable=cm)
    cm_entry.bind("<Key>", lambda event: convert_length(event, 'cm'))

    km_label = Label(length_frame, text="Kilometers").grid(row=2, column=0)
    km = IntVar()
    km_entry = Entry(length_frame, textvariable=km)
    km_entry.bind("<Key>", lambda event: convert_length(event, 'k'))

    # convert_length_button = Button(length_frame, text="Convert Length", command=convert_length)
    mm_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    cm_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    km_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
    # convert_length_button.grid(columnspan=2)

    # Temprature Converter

    c_label = Label(b_frame, text="Celsius")
    c = StringVar()
    c_entry = Entry(b_frame, textvariable=c)

    window.mainloop()
```

Could someone clarify how I can write a function to perform this?

Answer (score 2):

I refactored some of your code and here's a solution

```
#validates the input
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def convert_length(unit, event=None):

    if unit == 'm':

        val = mm_entry.get()             
        if (is_number(val)):
            mm = float(val)
            cm = mm / 10
            km = mm / 1000000     
            cm_entry.delete(0, END)
            km_entry.delete(0, END)
            cm_entry.insert(0, cm)
            km_entry.insert(0, km)

        else:
            cm_entry.delete(0, END)
            km_entry.delete(0, END)
            if (val == ''):
                cm_entry.insert(0, '')
                km_entry.insert(0, '')
            else:
                cm_entry.insert(0, 'NaN')
                km_entry.insert(0, 'NaN')

mm_label = Label(length_frame, text="Millimeters").grid(row=0)
mm_entry = Entry(length_frame)
mm_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda value : convert_length('m'))
```

For what you're trying to accomplish I suggest you use `"<KeyRelease>"` for the event handler as opposed to `"<Key>"`. The reason being are the `insert()` and `delete()` function of the `Entry()` widget are being delayed (is there a terminology for this?) in turn giving you the previous input's calculations for you output if you use `"<key>"`. Whereas `"<KeyRelease>"` will execute those functions right away allowing you to see the changes in the entry widgets.

If you want to see the effects of `"<Key>"`and `"<KeyRelease>"`simply switch them.

Just apply the same logic and pattern to your remaining units of calculation.